# Find an eigevector corresponding to each eigenvalue of the matrix (4,1)(2,3). Is this matrix diagonalisable?

Tags: linear-algebra

I've found the two Eigenvalues to be 5 and 2.
For eigenvalue 5, I have found the corresponding eigenvector to be (1,1)

For eigenvalue 2, I have found the corresponding equation to be x=-y/2. What is this in matrix form?

Comment: Also, what does diagonalisable mean?

Comment: If the eigenvalues are distinct, then the matrix is immediately diagonalizable.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_diagonalization#Diagonalization

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

- A matrix is diagonalizable when you have distinct eigenvalues.
- For $\lambda = 5, v_1 = (1,1)$ is correct.
- For $\lambda = 2, v_2$ is not correct.

Once you have the eigenvalue / eigenvector pairs, you can write the [*Jordan Normal Form*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form), that is, the diagonal $2x2$ matrix, using (of course, this is easy with distinct eigenvalues, but you should still work out as practice):

$$J = P^{-1}AP$$

- $P$ is made up of the eigenvectors you found above and you calculate $P^{-1}$.

Comment: Helpful hints +1

Answer (score 0):

An eigenvector shows a direction; hence, the important is the relation between the axis and not the scaling. Thus, if you have the equation $x=-y/2$, you can give a random value to $y$, and then get the $x$ value. For example, $y=1 \rightarrow x=-1/2$, but it is also valid $y=-2 \rightarrow x=1$, and so on. Hence, any eigenvector $(-1/2,1)$, $(1,-2)$, $(2,-4)$, $(-2,4)$, etc that satisfies the equation $x=-y/2$ can be used.

Once you select the eigenvector that you like, you can create the eigenvector matrix:

$$
\begin{bmatrix} \upsilon_1 & \upsilon_2 \end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 1 & -2 \end{bmatrix}
$$

Besides, it is common practice to have eigenvectors with norm 1.

$$
\begin{bmatrix} \bar{\upsilon_1} & \bar{\upsilon_2} \end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \\ 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} & \frac{-2}{\sqrt{5}} \end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} 0.707 & 0.447 \\ 0.707 & -0.894 \end{bmatrix}
$$
However, I must say that I don't think you extracted correctly the eigenvectors. The eigenvectors are orthogonal, $\upsilon_1 \cdot \upsilon_2 = 0$, which is not satisfied in your case.